# Arquivo .java sem assinatura de classe

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estava dando uma olhada no [código do PrimeFaces](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces), quando me deparei com a seguinte situação ([arquivo ButtonTemplate.java](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/button/ButtonTemplate.java)):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.primefaces.util.HTML;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils;

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Button.class.getName());

    public String resolveIcon() {
        String icon = getIcon();

        if(icon == null) {
            icon = getImage();

            if(icon != null)
                logger.info("image attribute is deprecated to define an icon, use icon attribute instead.");
        }

        return icon;
    }

    public String resolveStyleClass() {
        String icon = resolveIcon();
        Object value = getValue();
        String styleClass = ""; 

        if(value != null && ComponentUtils.isValueBlank(icon)) {
            styleClass = HTML.BUTTON_TEXT_ONLY_BUTTON_CLASS;
        }
        else if(value != null && !ComponentUtils.isValueBlank(icon)) {
            styleClass = getIconPos().equals("left") ? HTML.BUTTON_TEXT_ICON_LEFT_BUTTON_CLASS : HTML.BUTTON_TEXT_ICON_RIGHT_BUTTON_CLASS;
        }
        else if(value == null && !ComponentUtils.isValueBlank(icon)) {
            styleClass = HTML.BUTTON_ICON_ONLY_BUTTON_CLASS;
        }

        if(isDisabled()) {
            styleClass = styleClass + " ui-state-disabled";
        } 

        String userStyleClass = getStyleClass();
        if(userStyleClass != null) {
            styleClass = styleClass + " " + userStyleClass;
        }

        return styleClass;
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getParams() {
        return ComponentUtils.getUIParams(this);
    }
```

---

Nesse arquivo não existe a "declaração" de uma classe (ex: `public class ButtonTemplate { }`).

- O que é isso?
- Como isso funciona?

Comment: Tem "template" no nome, deve ser chamado em outra classe com assinatura correta.

Comment: Isso é uma "composição de classe"? @Articuno

Comment: Nesse caso, não é template de classe, mas template de código propriamente dito. O Java não consegue fazer muita coisa com o que foi fornecido, então o programador deve preencher as lacunas. Isso se repete em toda o diretório `java-template`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado como isso funciona?

Comment: Você copia, cola, preenche as lacunas de código. Como a declaração da classe, o fecha chaves da classe, declaração de pacote etc

Comment: Me parece ser algum caso onde ele copia e cola o código por aí e depois o altera para fazer alguma coisa.